# Chained builds using Jenkins and SVN?

Tags: c#, svn, jenkins

I'm attempting to set up a build hierarchy in Jenkins of this type:

1. A tools DLL gets built due to code changes checked in to SVN.
2. If that build succeeds, the DLL is then copied to the references directory for several other projects and checked in to SVN, thereby kicking off their Jenkins builds.

I know I can do this with a batch file after the DLL is built by just calling xcopy and svn from the command line, but is there a plugin specifically designed for this?  I looked at the parameterized build plugin, but it doesn't seem to support what I'm looking for:  the checking in of the newly generated DLL for all subsequent projects.

Is the batch file and command line solution the best way?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it via Post-Build-Action in Jenkins or in you words the "batch file and command line solution". I do not no any plugin which will do it excepted of xcopy (but I also have not been looking for it) ;-). I can't also see to much disadvantages in this solution. I mean you need no plugin, no additional dependencies, easy implementation. All in all not to bad.